# Selenium Webdriver - Apache POI - XSSF - 2nd loop is not getting executed

Tags: loops, selenium, webdriver

I’m using Apache POI to read data from multiple excel but my code doesn’t recognize the value from 2nd excel, It’s not even getting inside my 2nd FOR loop

Excel 1 – Test Data to login

Excel 2 – Course Details

My Login credentials is present in the 1st excel, It has 5 data in it. I would like to login with that user and add course for that user. Appreciate your help on this!!

Note # please suggest if you have any concerns on this piece of code
Below is the code that I’m using

```
package M1.Testcases;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Helper.BrowserFactory;
import M1.Pages.Add_Course;
import M1.Pages.LoginPage;

   public class CopyOfVerifyAdd_Course 
   {

WebDriver driver;
@Test
@Parameters("browser")
public void checkValidUser(String browser) throws IOException,   InterruptedException
{
    try  
    {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("File1Path")); 
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(new File("File2Path"));  
            XSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file1);
            XSSFSheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheetAt(0);
            String url= "1st URL";

          for (int i=1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
          {

              String uid = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

              String pass = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

              WebDriver driver=BrowserFactory.startBrowser(browser,url);

              LoginPage login_page=PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);

              login_page.login_MI(uid,pass);

              driver.get("2nd URL");
              driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


              for (int j=1; j <= sheet1.getLastRowNum(); j++)
              {
                  Thread.sleep(10000);
                  String course_title = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_code = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_cat_desc = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_full_desc = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_price = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_target_audience = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_learner_assess = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(6).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_copyright = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(7).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_release_date = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(8).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_review_date = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(9).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_expiration_date = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(10).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_state_req = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(11).getStringCellValue();
                  String course_bibi = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(12).getStringCellValue();

                  Add_Course add_course_page=PageFactory.initElements(driver, Add_Course.class);

                  driver.switchTo().frame(course_cat_desc);
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                  driver.switchTo().frame(course_full_desc);
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                  driver.switchTo().frame(course_target_audience);
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                  driver.switchTo().frame(course_learner_assess);
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                  driver.switchTo().frame(course_state_req);
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                  driver.switchTo().frame(course_bibi);
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                  add_course_page.AddCourse(course_title,course_code,course_cat_desc,course_full_desc,course_price,course_target_audience,course_learner_assess,
                          course_copyright,course_release_date,course_review_date,course_expiration_date,course_state_req,course_bibi);

                  Thread.sleep(10000);

              } 

              driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

              driver.quit();

          }
          workbook.close();
          file.close();
          workbook1.close();
          file1.close();
      }          
     catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) 
     {
         fnfe.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

}

Comment: Just before the 2nd for loop insert System.out.println("last row # " + sheet.getLastRowNum());  What is the value?

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your response. In my course excel data I had only one row so it was returning 0 value. I'm able to get thru it when I added 1st header row and 3 rows with course data. Appreciate your time and assistance!!